# What Field Type is my Selection in?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro in Word that searches a document, and then does things when found.

I would like to check if the Found text is in a table of contents, but it doesn't seem to be liking how I have the code:

```
Sub test()
Dim myDoc   As Word.Document
Dim oRng As Word.Range, rng As Word.Range, rngXE As Word.Range
Dim addDefinition$, editedDefinition$ ',findText$
Dim rngEdited
Dim bFound  As Boolean
Dim findText() As Variant
Dim y&

Set myDoc = ActiveDocument
bFound = True

Call Clear_Index

findText = Array("whatever", "whatever:", "Whatever:")

For y = LBound(findText) To UBound(findText)
'Loop through the document
Set oRng = myDoc.Content
Set rngXE = oRng.Duplicate
With oRng.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .ClearAllFuzzyOptions
    .Text = findText(y)
    .MatchCase = False
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
End With                     'orng.find

Do While bFound
    bFound = oRng.Find.Execute
    If bFound Then
        Set rngXE = oRng.Paragraphs(1).Range.Duplicate
        rngXE.Select

        '
        '  THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP :(
        If rngXE.Fields.Type = wdFieldTOC Then ' This doesn't work.
            MsgBox (" In a TOC!")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

It throws

> Compile Error: Method or data member not found

I've seen loops of

```
For each fld in myDoc.Fields
    If fld.Type = wbFieldTOC Then
      'Do something
    end if
next fld
```

Which work - I'm just having a hard time understanding to find specific text's field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `InRange` method is useful for discovering if one range is located within another range. Since there is a `TableOfContents` collection for the `Document` object, it's simple enough to get that range and test whether some other ange (even `Selection.Range`) is within it.

The following snippet assumes the document has a TOC and that you're interested in the first TOC. If your situation is otherwise, you need to do some checking to make sure the reference is to the correct TOC:

```
oRng.InRange(ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents(1).Range)
```

Comment: That's great! Thanks for this, I went with `If rngXE.InRange(myDoc.TablesOfContents(1).Range) = False Then ...`